# How to use the same super admin in WSO2 AM docker

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I changed the datasource from H2 to MSSQL, and WSO2 AM created the admin user. I created the endpoints, but when I restart the container (because I changed the port), WSO2 AM is in blank, but the database has the information user, endpoint, etc. how can I use the same information of the database in WSO2 AM.

Thanks

Comment: 1. How did you change the AM created admin user ? By changing values in user-mgt.xml or via carbon console ?

Comment: I just change the datasources, I should change the user-mgt.xml?, for example yesterder I changed the datasources, I created the endpoints, but today I want to create a new instance I change the datasources in this new instance, but it is blank, I created new endpoints, in the database has the yesterday informacion and today information but each instance has its information, I want to use the all information in any instance?

Answer (score 0):

"WSO2 AM is in blank, but the database has the information user, endpoint, etc. how can I use the same information of the database in WSO2 AM."              : What do you mean by here? Once you changed the database (H2 -> MsSQL) can't you see any created APIs in the publisher or store UI? If it is, did you migrate the H2 data from MsSQL database(AM DB data, Registry DB data and UM dB data)? If you have migrated data, in order to see the API in Publisher and Store UI, you can do the reindexing as mentioned here(5th step)[1]
[1]. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Upgrading+from+the+Previous+Release#UpgradingfromthePreviousRelease-Step2-UpgradeWSO2API-M2.5.0to2.6.0

Comment: Yes, I changed the database H2 to MSSQL, I created the endpoints, and I saw the information in the database MSSQL, but when I restore the container and change the datasources, that container is blank

Comment: The product container cannot be restarted just like that... usually when we kill a product container made out of the Docker images we provide u cannot reuse them
u need to create a new container instance
and provide the configurations, one can use any of the methods given here [1]. https://medium.com/faun/wso2-products-dockerized-advanced-usage-part-1-ae255ef02661